# In C#, how to get XML node value that is white space?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I have a XML node with a value which is a white space. Example:

```
<sampleNode> </sampleNode>
```

I am using a Serializer to get the data from XML document to store it in an object. Now, the problem I am facing is: If the XML node value contains nothing but a white space, as does the sample node above, the serializer interpretates it as a string.Empty.

How can I overcome this? I need get the actual white space, i.e. " ". Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you Oded, Phil and Laurent for your quick responses and correct answers. All your replies are true - however, my problem is still unresolved. Here's what I am using to convert the XML file to an object: 

    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(File.Open(Path, FileMode.Open));
    XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
    MyType obj = (MyType)Serializer.Deserialize(SR);
    return obj;

Any ideas still?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you are using XmlDocument, you should set the [PreserveWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) property to True.

If using and XmlReader set the [WhitespaceHandling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.whitespacehandling.aspx) property WhitespaceHandling.All.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387103.aspx) MSDN article about Preserving White Space While Serializing.

The different serializers handle this different ways, try using the [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) for this, as per [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/a5e411f1-b247-4e16-83c9-4a227b75883e) forum post.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though your solution is completely correct, I cannot apply it in my code, as I am not using neither XmlDocument nor XmlReader. I have added my code that converts XML file to an object in the post comment.

Comment: Well, what do you know: I started using XmlReader :D 
Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Sample class:

```
using System;

namespace GeneralTesting
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SampleNode
    {
        public string sampleNode = " ";
    }
}
```

And sample program:

```
    XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SampleNode));
    SampleNode sn = new SampleNode();
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\test.xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        xmls.Serialize(fs, sn);
    }
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test.xml"))
    {
        XmlReaderSettings xmlrs = new XmlReaderSettings();
        xmlrs.IgnoreWhitespace = false;
        using (XmlReader xmlr = XmlReader.Create(fs, xmlrs))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("!{0}!", ((SampleNode) xmls.Deserialize(xmlr)).sampleNode); //output: ! !
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and a nice sample on the XmlReader usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CDATA placeholder in order to avoid the removal of the space:

```
<sampleNode><![CDATA[ ]]></sampleNode>
```

Comment: Even thought your solution can solve my problem, I will be giving more time to the people to try to overcome the XmlSerializer issue I am facing with a more elegant solution. If however, no one comes up with the better idea, I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Have you tried to use the "&nbsp;" entity ? I just though about it.