# Force whitespace escape in XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

Is it possible to force the XmlSerializer to serialize a class like the following:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public string SomeString = " hello world ";
}
```

in something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dummy>
  <SomeString>&#x0020;hello&#x0020;world&#x0020;</SomeString>
</Dummy>
```

**EDIT**

in other words I need to preserve all whitespace in the original string, otherwise how can I tell if
a document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dummy>
  <SomeString>
     hello world</SomeString>
</Dummy>
```

contains the original whitespace before the word "hello"?

Comment: look intoi this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927006/in-c-how-to-get-xml-node-value-that-is-white-space

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: it seems that the link you provide explains how to preserve whitespace when deserializing. I need to force whitespace escaping when serializing. Or is it enough to preserve when deserializing?

Comment: @phoog I need for example leading or tailing spaces to be preserved.