# Add XML attribute to property when serializing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Right now when I serialize a string with whitespaces I get an empty string when deserializing it

I want to do something like this:

```
[XmlAttribute("xml:space=preserve")]
public string Category { get; set;}
```

and get this :

```
<Category xml:space="preserve">    </Category>
```

so when I deserialize it with the Xmlserializer I can get the whitespaces back.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1927020) answer

Comment: That would preserve the whitespace for all the other properties, but I just want to preserve it for this one.

Comment: Curious if you ever got this to work?

Comment: @OlivierDeMeulder, I do not remember,, but later I ended up creating my own xml serialization library: https://github.com/elios264/Persist/